# Find Replace using Values in another File

Tags: bash, awk, sed, terminal, find-replace

I have a directory of files, `myFiles/`, and a text file `values.txt` in which one column is a set of values to find, and the second column is the corresponding replace value.

The goal is to replace all instances of find values (first column of `values.txt`) with the corresponding replace values (second column of `values.txt`) in all of the files located in `myFiles/`.

For example...

`values.txt`:

Hello Goodbye

Happy Sad

Running the command would replace all instances of "Hello" with "Goodbye" in every file in `myFiles/`, as well as replace every instance of "Happy" with "Sad" in every file in `myFiles/`.

I've taken as many attempts at using awk/sed and so on as I can think logical, but have failed to produce a command that performs the action desired.

Any guidance is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You mention columns. Is `values.txt` a CSV file, or what are you using for _columns_

Comment: Hi @Un3qual, sorry for the late response. The file is simply two columns of text separated by a single space character. I did my best to display this in the question, but was having some issues with allowable formatting.

Thank you for taking interest in my question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read each line from `values.txt`
2. Split that line in 2 words
3. Use `sed` for each line to replace 1st word with 2st word in all files in `myFiles/` directory

Note: I've used bash [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) to split the line (`${line% *}` etc) , assuming `values.txt` is space separated 2 columnar file. If it's not the case, you may use `awk` or `cut` to split the line.

> ```
> while read -r line;do
>     sed -i "s/${line#* }/${line% *}/g" myFiles/*  # '-i' edits files in place and 'g' replaces all occurrences of patterns 
> done < values.txt
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with awk.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

# snarf in first file, values.txt
FNR == NR {
    subs[$1] = $2
    next
}

# apply replacements to subsequent files
{
    for( old in subs ) {
        while( index(old, $0) ) {
            start = index(old, $0)
            len = length(old)
            $0 = substr($0, start, len) subs[old] substr($0, start + len)
        }
    }
    print
}
```

When you invoke it, put `values.txt` as the first file to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Option One:

1. create a python script
2. with open('filename', 'r') as infile, etc., read in the values.txt file into a python dict with 'from' as key, and 'to' as value. close the infile.
3. use shutil to read in directory wanted, iterate over files, for each, do popen 'sed 's/from/to/g'" or read in each file interating over all the lines, each line you find/replace.

Option Two:

1. bash script
2. read in a from/to pair
3. invoke

   perl -p -i -e 's/from/to/g' dirname/*.txt

done

second is probably easier to write but less exception handling. 
It's called 'Perl PIE' and it's a relatively famous hack for doing find/replace in lots of files at once.